# golang type conversion not working as (I) expected

Tags: types, go, flags

I'm using [go-flags](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags) to parse command line options.

Per the go-flags docs:

> ... [if] either -h or --help was specified in the command line
> arguments, a help message will be automatically printed. Furthermore,
> the special error type ErrHelp is returned.

The method I'm calling is:

```
func (p *Parser) Parse() ([]string, error) {
```

I'm calling it with:

```
var opts struct {
    // ...
}

func main() {

    parser := flags.NewParser(&opts, flags.Default)

    args, err := parser.Parse()
```

A snippet from the file that defines ErrHelp looks like this:

```
type ErrorType uint

const (
    // Unknown or generic error
    ErrUnknown ErrorType = iota

    // Expected an argument but got none
    ErrExpectedArgument

    // ...

    // The error contains the builtin help message
    ErrHelp

    // ...
)

// Error represents a parser error. The error returned from Parse is of this
// type. The error contains both a Type and Message.
type Error struct {
    // The type of error
    Type ErrorType

    // The error message
    Message string
}

// Get the errors error message.
func (e *Error) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}

func newError(tp ErrorType, message string) *Error {
    return &Error{
        Type:    tp,
        Message: message,
    }
}
```

So they have this custom "Error" type.  And in the Parse() method above, internally, the error is getting created with a block of code like this:

```
    help.ShowHelp = func() error {
        var b bytes.Buffer
        p.WriteHelp(&b)
        return newError(ErrHelp, b.String())
    }
```

As you can see newError() returns "*Error" as it's type.  But the anonymous function just above returns type "error" - so those types must be compatible.(?)

But now back to the original problem - I'm just trying to see if my "err" is an "Error" and has member "Type" equal to ErrHelp.  So I try this:

```
if err != nil && flags.Error(err).Type == flags.ErrHelp {
```

Or even just this:

```
fmt.Printf("test:", flags.Error(err))
```

And either way the compiler gives me:

> main.go:37: cannot convert err (type error) to type flags.Error

But does not state why that conversion can't be done.  Any ideas?

(I don't get how "*Error" successfully converts to "error" in the anonymous function above, and I even more don't get why if that works then I can't convert it back the other way...  I must be missing something really dumb here, but I'm not seeing what it is.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An `error` is an interface with a single method `Error() string`. See http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error

A `flags.Error` has such a method, so it can be used as an `error`.

Conversely, however, a `flags.Error` is a struct, and there's no way to convert an arbitrary value to a struct.

What you *can* do is, and I think this is the answer to your question, is that if you've got a `flags.Value` inside an `error`, then you can cast the `error` back to the underlying type. The syntax for that is `e := err.(*flags.Error)`. This'll give you a value of type `*flags.Error` (or panic, if the underlying type isn't `*flags.Error`). You can avoid the panic in this case by using the comma-ok form, which is `e, ok := err.(*flags.Error)`.

Concretely, you would write:

```
  args, err := flags.Parse()
  if err != nil {
     if ferr, ok := err.(*flags.Error); ok {
       // ... something using ferr
     } else {
       // ... deal with non-flags.Error case, if that's possible.
     }
  }
```

Comment: Ok gotcha - thanks and that does work!  I can't find in the docs what that syntax means...  "err.(*flags.Error)" means "give me a pointer to err but with type flags.Error"?  (I'm assuming like you said I can't convert directly to Error, but I can convert to an Error pointer - that would make sense.)

Comment: The syntax `err.(*flags.Error)` is type assertion. More information: https://go.dev/tour/methods/15